# Ribbon shape button with icons and line on hover

Tags: css, button

I m trying to design a both and ribbon shape button on hover should show horizontal line and icon on both ends.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ifB8.jpg

```css
.right-left-flag {
          position: relative;
          background: black;
          padding: 22.1px 40px;
          color: #fff;
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .right-left-flag:before,
        .right-left-flag:after {
          border-color: #000 transparent;
          top: 0;
        }

        .right-left-flag:before,
        .right-left-flag:after {
          border-style: solid;
          height: 0;
          width: 0;
          display: block;
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
        }

        .right-left-flag:before {
          left: -19.5px;
          border-width: 33px 0 28.5px 20px;
        }
        
        .right-left-flag:after {
        right: -19.5px;
        border-width: 33px 20px 28.5px 0;
    }
```

```html
 <a href="#" class="right-left-flag">Read More</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please could you share your HTML as well as the CSS and let me know which part of the ribbon you are having trouble with.

Comment: i have share you the css which i have used, i m able to draw the ribbon shape on both side using pseudo elements after/before. but not able to get the icons and horizontal line

Comment: @BhaskarGaribidi Post your relevant html code as well man, so its easier for people to start helping you.. right now, nobody knows the structure of your codes..

Comment: @BhaskarGaribidi As I recommended earlier If you can share the HTML then I will be able to determine why the icons and lines don't display.

Comment: can you put complete code in the snippet

Comment: @MikePoole i have added code

Comment: @Aslam i have added code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you get some idea about how to do.

You can add any font icon to the after and before elements of the span inside the `content`.

```css
.right-left-flag {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  padding: 22px 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.right-left-flag:before,
.right-left-flag:after {
  border-color: #000 transparent;
  top: 0;
}

.right-left-flag:before,
.right-left-flag:after {
  border-style: solid;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.right-left-flag:before {
  left: -19.5px;
  border-width: 33px 0 28.5px 20px;
}

.right-left-flag:after {
  right: -19.5px;
  border-width: 33px 20px 28.5px 0;
}

.right-left-flag:hover>span {
  opacity: 1
}

.right-left-flag>span {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.right-left-flag>span:before {
  content: ':)';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.right-left-flag>span:after {
  content: ':)';
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="right-left-flag">Read More<span></span></a>
```

Comment: still i have doubt, button is center box is increasing on resolution change, how can i maintain the resolution?

Comment: how can i maintain same view in all resolution